# #pragma section and attributes

Tags: visual-c++, portable-executable

Just trying to make a new section and setting up his attributes with #pragma return this warning:

> warning C4330: attribute 'write' for section '.mysec' ignored

Simple code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma section(".mysec",execute,read,write)
__declspec(allocate(".mysec")) UCHAR var[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF};

void main() { return; }
```

*linker options: /DYNAMICBASE:NO, /FIXED, /NXCOMPAT:NO, /OPT:NOREF*

*OS/tools: Win x64 / msvc++ 110*

I read some articles on MSDN and in particulary this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50bewfwa(v=vs.110).aspx but didn't found answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this due to the `execute` flag. I don't think you can have a section that contains writeable code in Windows.

I might be remembering this wrong but it would a security issue and thus not supported.

Comment: At this moment, compiling without the execute attribute give no warning.

Comment: As expected. The execute flag means that code will be in that section. It will not support writeable. Removing execute changes it to a data section

Comment: is there any compiler setting to avoid this check and let a section be both executable and writable?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linker Command Line -> `/SECTION:.mysec,RWE`, Works perfectly.

Also you can use a tool like CFF Explorer to change section flag to E0000040 or manually parse your PE file and change it.